# By hindsight a question was too general - What to do?

Tags: discussion, questions

E.g. I asked the question "How to convince my colleagues to learn new technologies and programming languages?". But by hindsight I think my question was too general. What can I do about this, esp. w/o annoying the persons answering the question? I saw some questions, where questions have been closed by admin in cause of being to general, what happens to these questions?

Comment: You could flag the question and ask for it to be closed / or moved to another site (it seems more suited to programmers.stackexchange, however there's a good chance that it's going to be a duplicate on that site).  At the moment it's got 4 community off topic votes against it, so it may well get moved by the community anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your question was too general. I think the problem was that it doesn't match any of the categories listed in [SO's FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions):

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - matters that are unique to the programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

You don't have a question about *code*—you have a question about *people*. Those are often a better fit over at [programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

In fact, [your question was migrated there](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97223/how-to-convince-my-colleagues-to-learn-new-technologies-and-programming-languages) about an hour ago—although I expect that now that it's there, it will end up getting closed as a duplicate (most likely, of [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68073/how-do-you-convince-coworkers-stakeholders-to-try-new-technologies)).

Comment: Indeed, I recognized that and then I wondered how to close or "transport" this question to another board (as somebody did meanwhile (thanks for this)) w/o annoying the people answering the question.

Comment: As @forsvarir wrote in a comment, one approach would have been to flag it for mod attention yourself and request that it be migrated to programmers.se.

Comment: I see, I will do better next time.